# How do I get a gltfpack-processed model to appear in A-Frame?

Tags: three.js, aframe, gltf

I compressed my models and textures with [gltfpack](https://github.com/zeux/meshoptimizer/tree/master/gltf) and now they are invisible in A-Frame 1.1.0. In gltfpack, I used -tc to convert the texture files to BasisU and left everything else as is. When I loaded them in A-Frame, the models aren't there. Interestingly, the models work in [Don McCurdy's viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/). *Update*: there is a relevant Javascript console message

> THREE.GLTFLoader: setKTX2Loader must be called before loading KTX2
> textures.

So it appears I'm misusing Three.js.

Here is a [bare Glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/db924de2-0a5a-4b1b-90c0-6894984369e5) showing the issue. There should be two models visible in the scene but only the unprocessed one is there. Anyone know I could fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The models are working with [Don's viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) because he isn't using the standard `gltf-model` component, but uses a [raw threejs loader](https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/blob/master/src/viewer.js#L222-L225)(with multiple extras):

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader().setCrossOrigin('anonymous');
loader.setDRACOLoader(new DRACOLoader().setDecoderPath('./wasm/'));
loader.setKTX2Loader(new KTX2Loader().detectSupport(renderer));
```

Afaik the KTX2Loader on the threejs repo is available only as a module ([here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/jsm/loaders)), so I've managed to make it work by creating my own module which imports the KTX2Loader. In a nutshell:

```
// probably only need the KTX2Loader since aframe gives access to 
// the GLTFLoader and DRACOLoader.
import { GLTFLoader } from './path_to_three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { KTX2Loader } from './path_to_three/examples/jsm/loaders/KTX2Loader.js';
import { DRACOLoader } from './path_to_three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js';

// this is a 'minimal' version of the gltf-component,
// a more faithful one is linked later on
module.exports.Component = 
AFRAME.registerComponent("full-gltf-model", 
   schema: { type: 'model' },
   init: function() { 
      const loader = new GLTFLoader().setCrossOrigin('anonymous')
               .setDRACOLoader(new DRACOLoader().setDecoderPath('./wasm/'))
               .setKTX2Loader(new KTX2Loader().detectSupport(renderer));
      var src = this.data;
      // load the model:
      loader.load(src, 
         function gltfLoaded(gltfModel) {
            let model = self.model = gltfModel.scene || gltfModel.scenes[0];
            // assuming el is an entity;
            el.setObject3D("mesh", model);
         }, undefined /* in progress */, 
         function error(err) {
            console.log("error:", err);         
      })
   }
})
```

I've bundled it with `browserify` (`browserify index.js -p esmify > dist/full-gltf-model.js`), and used like this:

```
<!-- Somewhere in the scripts -->
<script src="dist/full-gltf-model.js>
<!-- Somewhere in the scene -->
<a-entity full-gltf-model="#model"></a-entity>
```

---

You can check it out [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/gltf-packed/index.html). The models are straight from Your glitch (credited to you ofc).

Feel free to check out the [directory](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/tree/master/aframe/gltf-packed) with the component and package.json. I'm pretty sure the bundle contains already defined stuff (1Mb even with only the KTX2Loader imported o.O), so there definitely is room for improvement. Still this seems like a good start :)

Comment: @chekeichan please let me know 1) If its understandable whatsoever, 2) If it's okay that I've used your models 3) If so, can I upload them on my gh (with credit), to get rid of the links to glitch which could break.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Yes, feel free to use my models. Your answer is understandable but whether I can apply it is another matter! I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: Yes, I can get your solution to work on my site and I'm learning a lot of useful information figuring out how it works. Thank you again.

Comment: @chekeichan glad i could help :)

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski holy god this is just the perfect answer, you even create a new component for A-Frame and demo the whole thing on github, thank you for this solution!

Answer (score 2):

Just want to provide an updated answer to this--this is now natively supported in A-Frame. Just do the following:

```html
    <a-scene gltf-model="dracoDecoderPath: https://www.gstatic.com/draco/v1/decoders/;
                         basisTranscoderPath:https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/super-three@0.141.0/examples/js/libs/basis/;;
                         meshoptDecoderPath: https://unpkg.com/meshoptimizer@~0.18.1/meshopt_decoder.js;">
```

Note: that basisTranscoderPath is only on master right now--so, not included yet in A-Frame 1.3.0, you'd have to pull master and run a build at the moment. Next release will have it, though. (see [the PR](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/5101/files#))

See the docs on this: https://github.com/jameskane05/aframe/blob/9df1d2cb50ab12aa341cc250c703624510d25deb/docs/components/gltf-model.md

The official master build links are currently lagging behind, and using a github cdn won't work because dist files are not being committed in the last few months, but I made a build and put it on a glitch project of mine--you can use that file at this link if you need this if aframe 1.3.0 is still the most recent version out for you:

https://gltf-packed.glitch.me/aframe-diego.js

(this is a dev build of a particular branch of diego's fork as of oct 15 2022)